# Using polar coordinates to solve a double integral

Tags: integration

I am working through some double integral questions in practice for my upcoming exam. The question I am stuck on is the following:
$\iint_R x^2y^2dxdy$ where $R \equiv x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 = 1$.
I am told to use $x=ar\cos(\theta)$ and $y = br\sin(\theta)$ and polar coordinates. I am more interested in the method than the answer if anyone could be kind enough to shed some light!

So far I have tried substituting the $x$ and $y$ equations into the equation for region R which simplified to give $r^2=1$. I then substituted the $x$ and $y$ equations into the original integral to give me: $a^2b^2\int^{\pi}_0\cos^2(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)\int^1_0r^4$ - I am slightly apprehensive about the limits, I cant help thinking I need to set the r integral from -1 to 1 but cant see the logic behind this? I am also confused about changing the variable of integration because I can only take partial derivatives of the $x$ and $y$ equations?

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track, but by the multivariate [change of variables formula](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcIII/ChangeOfVariables.aspx) you need to account for the Jacobian matrix of this change of variables and tweak your bounds a bit, //i.e.//

\begin{align*}
    \iint_Rx^2y^2\,dxdy &= \iint_{\{(r,\theta) : r = 1\}} (ar\cos\theta)^2(br\sin\theta)^2\left|\begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(ar\cos\theta) & \frac{\partial}{\partial r}(br\sin\theta) \\ \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(ar\cos\theta) & \frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}(br\sin\theta)\end{pmatrix}\right|\,dr d\theta\\
    &= \int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^1 a^3b^3r^5\cos^2\theta\sin^2\theta\,drd\theta\\
    &= \ldots
\end{align*}

Note here that you can make the $\theta$ bound range from $0$ to $2\pi$ (not just $\pi$) to account for the whole disk $R$ rather than think about negative $r$!

Comment: Thank you! I will read into it

Comment: After working through it using the link you kindly provided I had an r^5 term not an r^3 - I got r^4 from the expansion of the brackets plus an abr term from the change of variables - Have I missed something?

Comment: Nope! Good catch! That should be an $r^5$. Sorry for the typo!

Comment: Ah okay! Many thanks again for helping me with this!